# Calculating date difference based on condition

Tags: javascript, date, calculation, crf

I am trying to using different dates in the condition to calculate a date difference. 
My calculations are based on the conditions below:

Scenario 1: SAE Onset Date < Drug Start Date or no Drug Start Sate
                Dose Duration: “Prior to drug treatment”

Scenario 2: SAE Onset Date >= Drug Start Date and SAE Onset Date <= Drug Stop Date or No Drug Stop Date
                Dose Duration: SAE Onset Date – Drug Start Date + 1 + “ days”

Scenario 3: SAE Onset Date > Drug Stop Date
                Dose Duration: SAE Onset Date – Drug Stop Date + “ days post last dose”

The code below is a modification from the first version, which only used 2 dates, and it was working correctly. But when applying the 3rd date to the condition, it is not working anymore. Not sure what I am doing wrong in the DiffInDays function.

```
<script src="includes/jmesa/jquery.min.js">// for OC versions before 3.1.4, use jquery-1.3.2.min.js !</script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
var fieldDate1 = $("#onsetDT").parent().parent().find("input");
var fieldDate2 = $("#startDT").parent().parent().find("input");
var fieldDate3 = $("#endDT").parent().parent().find("input");
var fieldDiff = $("#Diff").parent().parent().find("input");

function OCDateToJDate(OCDate){
 var dateParts = OCDate.split("-");
 var JDate = new Date(1900,1,1);
 JDate.setFullYear(dateParts[2]);
 JDate.setMonth(Calendar._SMN.indexOf(dateParts[1]));
 JDate.setDate(dateParts[0]);
 return JDate;
 }
function DiffInDays(OCDate1, OCDate2, OCDate3){
 var msecPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
 var onsetdt=OCDateToJDate(OCDate1).getTime();
 var startdt=OCDateToJDate(OCDate2).getTime();
 var enddt=OCDateToJDate(OCDate3).getTime();
 if (((onsetdt>=startdt) && (onsetdt<=enddt)) || (enddt==='')){
     var days = Math.round((onsetdt - startdt)/ msecPerDay );
      return days+1+" days";
     }
 if ((onsetdt<startdt) || (startdt==='')){
     return "Prior to drug treatment"
     }
 if(onsetdt>startdt){
     var days = Math.round((onsetdt-enddt) / msecPerDay );
      return days+" days post last dose "; } 
}
function calcDiff(){
 var calculatedDifference = DiffInDays(fieldDate1.val(), fieldDate2.val(), fieldDate3.val());
 if (fieldDiff.val() != calculatedDifference){
  fieldDiff.val(calculatedDifference);
  fieldDiff.change();
 }
};
fieldDate1.blur(function(){ calcDiff(); });
fieldDate2.blur(function(){ calcDiff(); });
fieldDate3.blur(function(){ calcDiff(); });
fieldDiff.blur(function(){ calcDiff(); })
fieldDiff.focus(function(){
 calcDiff();
 })
$("#srl").focus(function(){
 calcDiff();
 });
$("#srh").focus(function(){
 calcDiff();
 });
})
</script>
```

The result would follow the condition I mentioned previously.

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This is invalid JavaScript and also not an [mcve]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by invalid. I am using the OpenClinica software and one of the ways to modify their forms is using javascript. I think the focus of my problem is the function DiffInDays(date1, date2, date3), what am I doing wrong in that particular function.

Comment: `if{date2>date3){`: that is a syntax error. The Javascript you included is invalid. Please edit your question.

Comment: I have updated, it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for empty date by comparing to an empty string - however, the function `OCDateToJDate()` returns a Date, not a String.

```
function OCDateToJDate(OCDate)
{
 var dateParts = OCDate.split("-");
 var JDate = new Date(1900,1,1);
 if(dateParts.length === 3) 
 {
   JDate.setFullYear(dateParts[2]);
   JDate.setMonth(Calendar._SMN.indexOf(dateParts[1]));
   JDate.setDate(dateParts[0]);
 }
 return JDate;
}

function DiffInDays(OCDate1, OCDate2, OCDate3)
{
 var msecPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
 var empty = (new Date(1900,1,1)).getTime();
 var onsetdt=OCDateToJDate(OCDate1).getTime();
 var startdt=OCDateToJDate(OCDate2).getTime();
 var enddt=OCDateToJDate(OCDate3).getTime();
 if ((onsetdt<startdt) || (startdt===empty))
 {
     return "Prior to drug treatment"
 }
 if (((onsetdt>=startdt) && (onsetdt<=enddt)) || (enddt===empty))
 {
     var days = Math.round((onsetdt - startdt)/ msecPerDay );
     return (days+1) + " days";
 }
 if(onsetdt>startdt)
 {
     var days = Math.round((onsetdt-enddt) / msecPerDay );
     return days + " days past last dose "; 
 } 
}
```